# woocommerce order in database but not in dashboard and not in order export

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**CURRENTLY**

I use wooCommerce for wordpress.
I have an order in the database I can see in phpmyadmin #2797

[image]

**ISSUE**

- all orders excluding order #2797 appear in wooCommerce dashboard
- all orders excluding order #2797 appear in CSV export from wooCommerce (I have tried multiple export / import plug-ins and they have the same issue)

[image]

**QUESTION**

1. How do I restore the order #7297 to WooCommerce dashboard if it's not appearing in WooCommerce orders export?
2. Is there another setting somewhere in the database that determines what orders show up in WooCommerce dashboard, and for some reason 7297 is excluded? Or could it be that there is a missing piece of data on 7297 that is causing it to not appear on the dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to wooCommerce support I diagnosed the problem and was able to find a fix.

**Problem**

The reason order #7297 was appearing in the database `_wc_order_stats` but not in WooCommerce Dashboard, was because for an order to appear in WooCommerce Dashboard, it needs an entry into db table `_posts` with *post type* `shop_order`. This was missing. I suspect it might have been lost when I completed an updraft migration.

**Solution**

1. Manually add an entry into `_posts` for order *7297*, and this adds the order back to WooCommerce dashboard, but with all the order data missing i.e. products purchased, price, payment, customer, shipping etc. *Adding back the order to `_posts` appears to have caused it to overwrite the corresponding entries in other tables.*
2. In WooCommerce dashboard, ensure order is in "Pending" state, this will allow editing of the order. Add back all the data manually. This updates the corresponding tables in WooCommerce.

All fixed!